# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError and GC overhead limit

Tags: java, heap-memory

I have got 5 million tuples and insert mysql from java. But I get an error out of memory in eclipse. I configured `eclipse.ini` last lines like that;

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

But I get an error again. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: What are they tuples of? And do you really *have* to have them all in memory at the same time?

Comment: If you are running on Windows 32 bits the JVM has a max limit of 2GB for the memory it can use.

Comment: Don't throw more memory to the problem. The problem is probably in the code. It may be better to read/write them in batch blocks.

Comment: If you want to modify Java Options you shouldn't do it in `eclipse.ini` because eclipse itself doesn't have such memory requirement.

Comment: @JonSkeet Tuples are address information. I do not have them all in memory at the same time so what should I do?

Comment: @user2984369: Are you *sure* you haven't got them all in memory? It's impossible for us to tell that as you haven't shown us any code...

Comment: @prmottajr     I am running 64 bits JVM. I try 2GB memory but in this time I get an error Java heap space.